# Speedometer needle rotation in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am making a mobile car game, in which i want the phone's sensor to animate the speedometer's needle. I want it to rotate from the dash pointing on 0 till the maximum point.

Needle pointing on minimum:

[image: Here is the needle pointing on minimum]

Needle pointing on maximum:

[image: Here is the needle pointing on maximum]

The rotation of the needle when pointing on minimum is 222 in Z, and -43 for maximum 
, when i attached the script below to the needle, it rotates from minimum to maximum. but anticlockwise and stop when reaches max, doesn't move according to my phone's accelerometer readings.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    static float minAnlge = 222.0F;
    static float maxAngle = -43.0F;
    static RotationControl thisSpeedo;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        thisSpeedo = this;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float ang = Mathf.LerpAngle(222, -43, Time.time);

        float z = Input.acceleration.x;
        if (z != 0)
        {
            thisSpeedo.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, ang);
        }
    }
}
```

When i changed the ang variable in last line to -ang, it rotates clockwise from minimum but doesn't reach max it stops in the point attached in the image below.

The angle in which needle stops:

[image: The angle in which needle stops]

The needle doesn't update it's movement, it stops when reaching the point in third image.

Comment: FYI, this is pointless: `thisSpeedo = this;`: `this` will always reference "this object" in all contexts (there are exceptions to this, but it deals with delegates, lambdas, and other weird things, none of which you are using). i.e. `this.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, ang);` will work just fine.

Comment: Many thanks for help.